# Getting code 500 back from Sling API JSON Post

Tags: javascript, json, http, google-apps-script

So it seems that Sling ([sling.is](http://sling.is)) updated [their API](https://api.sling.is), but never sent out an email with warning or information, so my script is broken. The end goal of my code (which worked fine prior to their update) is to simply post shifts for employees to Sling upon a company event being approved.

I'm running all of this code in google apps script since I need to pull data from a spreadsheet to create the shifts. The code works by first "adding" the shifts to the system, and then secondly "publishing" those shifts so all employees can see them. I managed to figure out how to fix the first part as it seems they switched some basic syntax around. But I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix the second (publishing) part.

Sling doesn't offer any support for their API, so I thought posting here would be my next best bet.

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> "Request failed for https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync returned code
>   500. Truncated server response: {"message": "Oops, an unexpected error occured."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
>   (line 257, file "Code")"

```
//CREATE SHIFTS ON SLING
     //This is pulling data from google spreadsheet cells
  var staff = getByName('Attendants', row);
  var start = Utilities.formatDate(getByName('Date', row), 
ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd") + "T" + 
Utilities.formatDate(getByName('Starting Time of Attendants', row), 
ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "H:mm") + ":00.000-04";
  var end = Utilities.formatDate(getByName('Date', row), 
ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "YYYY-MM-dd") + "T" + 
Utilities.formatDate(getByName('Ending Time of Attendants', row), 
ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "H:mm") + ":00.000-04";
  var notes = getByName('City', row) + ", " + getByName('Event Type', row)

  var payload = {
  "available": true,
  "dtstart": start,  
  "dtend": end,
  "location": {
    "id": 1022310
  },
  "position": {
    "id": 1022302
  },
  "summary": notes,
  "user": {
    "id": 1
  }
  };

  var headers = {
   "Authorization" : "9e632842f4e61927336337f1aa65b75c"
  };

  var options = {

  'method' : 'post',                  
  'contentType': 'application/json', 
  'headers' : headers,
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(payload)


};
  for(i=1; i<=staff; i++){
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts? 
ignoreConflicts=false&publish=true", options);
  }
// All of that ^^ works               

  var payloadtwo = 
    {
      "summary": notes
  };          


  var optionstwo = {

  'method' : 'post',                  
  'contentType': 'application/json', 
  'headers' : headers,
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(payloadtwo)


  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync", optionstwo);
```

I even tried completely removing the payload (body) parameter from the JSON options.

```
  var payloadtwo = { 
  "summary": notes, 
  "dtstart": "2018-11-07T12:00:00:00.000-04", 
  "dtend": "2018-11-09T12:00:00:00.000-04" 
  };        


var optionstwo = {

'method' : 'post',                  
'contentType': 'application/json', 
'headers' : headers


};

UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync", optionstwo);
```

and then it says

> "Request failed for https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync returned code 400. 
>   Truncated server response: 
>   {"message": "Publishing requires either a date range or a list of
>   events"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
>   (line 256, file "Code")"

Sling API's "documentation" for the shift posting feature is available here: https://api.sling.is/#/shifts/post_shifts_sync

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can we ask you about your current situation? The error message says ``Publishing requires either a date range or a list of events``. Have you already considered about this?

Comment: Yes. I've added dates in the correct ISO 8601 format, and it then throws the first error message code 500.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Is the script in your question your latest version?

Comment: Yes, it is what my script is right now. I've tried everything I can think of, nothing is making that last part work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the error of ``Publishing requires either a date range or a list of events`` and your script in your question, it seems that ``a date range or a list of events`` is not used. So how about considering about it?

Comment: I added times, and it is still throwing code 500. My payload is now `var payloadtwo = 
    {
      "summary": notes,
      "dtstart": "2018-11-07T12:00:00:00.000-04",
      "dtend": "2018-11-09T12:00:00:00.000-04"
  };`  and the error message is `Request failed for https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync returned code 500. Truncated server response: {"message": "Oops, an unexpected error occured."} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 259, file "Code")`

Comment: It was found that your script in the question is difference from your current one. Could you please add it to your question as update? Because it is difficult to understand the script in the comment from users including me. Can we think that ``payloadtwo`` is put in ``optionstwo`` and the response from ``UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync", optionstwo);`` is the error?

Comment: Original post has been updated. And yes, that is correct - still receiving the error with start and end times added. The shifts are getting added on the day between the start and end times, but it's throwing the code 500 when I try to "publish" the shifts using the last `UrlFetchApp.fetch`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I posted a modified script. Could you please try to run? If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From [the API document](https://api.sling.is/#/shifts/post_shifts_sync) in your question, it seems that the request body is an object including an array. And it seems that the key is `event`. So could you please try this modified script? When you run this, please set `notes` and `headers`.

#### Modified script :

```
var payloadtwo = {
  "event": [ // or "Event"
    {
      "summary": notes,
      "dtstart": "2018-11-07T12:00:00:00.000-04",
      "dtend": "2018-11-09T12:00:00:00.000-04",
    }
  ]
};
var optionstwo = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payloadtwo),
  'headers': headers,
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync", optionstwo);
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note :

- If the error occurs, please modify from `'payload': JSON.stringify(payloadtwo),` to `'payload': payloadtwo,` and run it again.

I couldn't try to test because I have no account. So if this script occurs the error, please tell me. I would like to think of other modification points.

### Edit 1 :

#### Modified script :

```
var payloadtwo = [
  {
    "summary": notes,
    "dtstart": "2018-11-07T12:00:00:00.000-04",
    "dtend": "2018-11-09T12:00:00:00.000-04",
  }
];
var optionstwo = {
  'method': 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload': JSON.stringify(payloadtwo), // or payloadtwo
  'headers': headers,
  'muteHttpExceptions': true,
};
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts/sync", optionstwo);
Logger.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still getting the same error messages. `notes` is assigned, and `headers` is assigned. Both of those are used in the first step, and both work just fine. When I used your code with the `JSON.stringify`, I get `{"message": "Oops, an unexpected error occured."}`. Then without `JSON.stringify`, I get `{"message": "Publishing requires either a date range or a list of events"}`. The event shift time is 4:15-9:15pm EDT (-04) on November 8th (2018-11-08). So the times I have as `dtstart` and `dtend` should cover that just fine.

Comment: @Alex James I'm really sorry for the inconvenience and my poor skill. I updated my answer. Could you please try to run it again?

Comment: No need to be sorry, you're helping. So this time with the edited code, when I run it without `JSON.stringify`, I get an error code at the top (not in logs) saying `Attribute provided with invalid value: payload (line 255, file "Code")`. When I run it with `JSON.stringify`, I get `{"message": "Oops, an unexpected error occured."}` in the logs.

Comment: @Alex James For example, for above script in my answer, could you modify from ``event`` to ``Event`` and try it again? And when the error occurs, can I ask you about the other documentation or samples for the API?

Comment: @Alex James By the way, it seems that there are ``"id": 0,`` for the sample request body in the document. Is it required to be included?

Comment: Changing `event` to `Event` still gives the same error messages. There is no more documentation or examples other than the original link that I provided. `"id": 0,` should not be required as it does not have a red asterisk next to it. I'm experimenting with it however.

Comment: @Alex James Thank you for testing them. I understand the situation. I cannot test by myself because I have no account for it. So I'm sorry I couldn't help. By the way, about ``All of that ^^ works`` in your script, the request for ``https://api.sling.is/v1/shifts`` worked? If it works, when I saw the document, there is no payload information. Where did you read the usage of it?

Comment: Ok, so I experimented with `id`. Was able to publish an event. I logged the `UrlFetchApp` for the first part. From the logs, I could find the actual IDs of the created (but not yet published) events. Then I just inserted one of those IDs into `id`, and the shift published. That's without entering anything into `summary`, `dtstart`, or `dtend`. Now I wonder what the best way is to publish all of the created shifts at once. It makes me wonder if my `dtend` and `dtstart` formats are wrong. Very weird that `id` worked, but the others did not. Also, this is using my original code, but using `id`.

Comment: @Alex James Where did you read the document for publishing an event?

Comment: It's under the "shifts" section, at POST /shifts/sync

Comment: @Alex James No, it's the document for ``All of that ^^ works``. I couldn't find the detail of payload you use at the "shifts" section. Does I misunderstand about it?

Comment: Try this: api.sling.is/#/shifts/post_shifts_sync . The main problem I'm having now is I am unable to put multiple shift IDs in the `"id":` part. It will only take one at a time. I have tried an array, but it will not take it. According to the documentation, the data type for `"id":` is an integer. Is there anyway I can put multiple shift IDs here?

Comment: @Alex James I'm sorry for the inconvenience. In order to know about this API, I think that it is required to directly test this API. But in my current situation, I cannot test. So I have only a little information for this API. For your current situation, I'm really sorry I couldn't help.